# rsync filtering

Tags: unix, rsync

I use an rsync command to sync two directories remote >local

the command is (used in python script)

```
os.system('rsync --verbose --progress --stats --recursive\
          --copy-links --times --include="*/" --include="*good_name*.good_ext*"\
          --exclude-from "/myhome/mydir/src/rsync.exclude"\
          %s %s'%(remotepath,localpath))
```

I want to exclude certain directories that has the same files that I also want to include.

I want to include recursively

```
any_dir_name/any_file_name.good
```

but I want to exclude any and all files that are in

```
bad_dir_name/
```

I used `--exclude-from` and here is my exclude from file

```
*
/*.bad_dir_name/
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work.  I suspect it may have something to do with `--include="*/"` but if I remove it the command doesn't sync any files at all.

Comment: I suggest you try asking this on superuser.com

Comment: Have you tried looking at the -f option? It's covered in the man page under FILTER RULES. Alternatively, a quick and dirty solution might be writing a `find` command combined with a print action and output to a file. There you go, instant perfect exclude file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I used `-vv` to find according to which rule the directory was showing up in the sync list and since rsync supports regular expressions, 
I changed my include statement from `"*/"` to

```
--include="*[^.bad_dir_name]/"
```

and all works fine now.

Comment: No, rsync does not support regular expressions in its filters.  It supports simple glob expressions (see https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html). What you really did is only include directories whose names do not end with the character 
. (period), b, a, d, _, i, r, n, m, or e.  So you'd miss any directory named "food" or "bin", for example.